# How to stop sticky sidebar overlapping footer?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this one out. Managed to get the sticky sidebar working except I need it to revert to position relative when it reaches the footer to avoid overlap.

Here's my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nedxtt0j/3/) of what I have so far, could someone please explain to me where I'm going wrong?

```
var top = $('.sidebar-container').offset().top - parseFloat($('.sidebar-container').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var footerTop = $('footer').offset().top - parseFloat($('footer').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar-container').outerHeight();
var s = $(".sidebar-container");
var pos = s.position(); 

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() + 200;
  var stickyBottomPos = sidebarHeight + top;    

  if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
     s.addClass('leftsidebarfixed');
  } else if (stickyBottomPos >= footerTop) {
     var stopPosition = footerTop - sidebarHeight;
     s.removeClass('leftsidebarfixed').css({top: stopPosition});
  } else { 
     s.removeClass('leftsidebarfixed');
  }
});
```

**Update:**

I've made further improvements which might help others, I just need to get the position it stops being fixed above the footer right.

Heres a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nedxtt0j/5/).

```
var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebar-container').outerHeight();
var s = $(".sidebar-container");
var pos = s.position(); 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var limit = $('footer').offset().top - sidebarHeight;
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 200; // returns number

    if (pos.top < windowTop){
      s.addClass('leftsidebarfixed');
    } else {
      s.removeClass('leftsidebarfixed').css('top', 200);
    }

    if (limit < windowTop) {
      var diff = limit - windowTop;
      s.css({top: diff});
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.